# #ajax callback uses the wrong callback

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I don't know why, but using this code, when I click on the *marker-category-add-submit* button, it executes the *type_callback* callback, and not *marker_category_add_callback*. Why?

If I comment all marker-type fields in my form, it uses the right callback.

```
function food_truck_form_admin() {
  $content_types = get_content_types();
  $markers_categories = variable_get('food_truck_form_marker_categories', array());
  $vocabulary = get_vocabulary();
  $marker_types = get_marker_types($vocabulary->machine_name);

  // MARKER CATEGORY
  $form['marker-category']['#markup'] = '<h2>Gestion des catégories de marqueurs</h2>';
  $form['marker-category']['#prefix'] = '<div id="category-wrapper">';

  $form['marker-category-add'] = array(
      '#title' => t('Nom'),
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#prefix' => '<div class="row"><div class="column">',
      '#options' => $content_types,
      '#description' => t('Ajouter une catégorie de marqueur')
  );
  $form['marker-category-add-submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
      '#value' => t('Ajouter'),
      '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'marker_category_add_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'category-wrapper',
        'event' => 'click'
      )
  );
  $form['marker-category-remove'] = array(
      '#title' => t('Supprimer des catégories de marqueurs'),
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#prefix' => '<div class="column">',
      '#multiple' => TRUE,
      '#validated' => TRUE,
      '#options' => $markers_categories
  );
  $form['marker-category-remove-submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#value' => t('Supprimer'),
      '#suffix' => '</div></div></div>',
      '#ajax' => array(
          'callback' => 'marker_category_remove_callback',
          'wrapper' => 'category-wrapper',
          'event' => 'click'
      )
  );

  // TEST ZONE

  $form['marker-type'] = array(
      '#title' => t('test'),
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#prefix' => '<div class="type-wrapper">'
  );
  $form['marker-type-submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#value' => t('Ajouter'),
      '#ajax' => array(
          'callback' => 'type_callback',
          'wrapper' => 'type-wrapper',
          'event' => 'click'
      )
  );
  $form['marker-type-list'] = array(
      '#title' => t('test'),
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
      '#multiple' => TRUE,
      '#validated' => TRUE,
      '#options' => array()
  );

  // $form = array_merge($form, generate_marker_types_management_form($markers_categories));

  $form['marker-wrapper-end']['#suffix'] = '</div>';

  // ATTACHEMENTS
  $form['#attached']['css'] = array(
      drupal_get_path('module', 'food_truck_form') . '/css/global.css',
      drupal_get_path('module', 'food_truck_form') . '/css/config_form.css'
  );
  $form['#submit'][] = 'food_truck_form_admin_submit';
  return system_settings_form($form);
}

function type_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  array_push($form['marker-type-list'], $form_state['value']['marker-type']);
  return array(
      $form['marker-type'],
      $form['marker-type-submit'],
      $form['marker-type-list']
  );
}

/**
 * CALLBACK : Ajouter une catégorie de marqueur
 */
function marker_category_add_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  // On récupère la clé et le nom de la catégorie
  $key = $form_state['values']['marker-category-add'];
  $marker_name = $form['marker-category-add']['#options'][$key];

  // On récupère les catégories existantes
  $food_truck_form_marker_categories = variable_get('food_truck_form_marker_categories', array());
  // Si on ajoute une catégorie qui n'existe pas déjà
  if (!array_key_exists($key, $food_truck_form_marker_categories)) {
    // On sauvegarde les catégories
    $food_truck_form_marker_categories[$key] = $marker_name;
    variable_set('food_truck_form_marker_categories', $food_truck_form_marker_categories);
    drupal_set_message(t('La catégorie de marqueur à été ajouté'));
    $form['marker-category-remove']['#options'] = $food_truck_form_marker_categories;
  } else {
    drupal_set_message(t('Cette catégorie de marqueur à déjà été ajouté !'), 'warning');
  }
  return array(
      $form['marker-category'],
      $form['marker-category-add'],
      $form['marker-category-add-submit'],
      $form['marker-category-remove'],
      $form['marker-category-remove-submit']
  ); // return array_merge(get_return_callback($form), generate_marker_types_management_form($food_truck_form_marker_categories));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was using différent '#name' in my buttons ;) coworker found the solutions :D